# How do I check fglrx's version?

Tags: fglrx

I'd like to know the version of fglrx installed in my Ubuntu 10.04.3 box. I'm not familiar with fglrx, so I found several ways by Google.

1

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep fglrx

[...]
(II) fglrx(0): Kernel Module Version Information:
(II) fglrx(0):     Name: fglrx
(II) fglrx(0):     Version: 8.72.11
(II) fglrx(0):     Date: Apr  8 2010
(II) fglrx(0):     Desc: ATI FireGL DRM kernel module
(II) fglrx(0): Kernel Module version matches driver.
(II) fglrx(0): Kernel Module Build Time Information:
(II) fglrx(0):     Build-Kernel UTS_RELEASE:        2.6.32-37-generic
(II) fglrx(0):     Build-Kernel MODVERSIONS:        yes
(II) fglrx(0):     Build-Kernel __SMP__:            yes
(II) fglrx(0):     Build-Kernel PAGE_SIZE:          0x1000
(II) fglrx(0): [uki] register handle = 0x00004000
[...]
```

2

```
ls /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/
8.723.1  kernel-2.6.32-37-generic-x86_64
```

3

In System->Administration->Synaptic Package Manager, I searched out the 'fglrx' package, It says 'Installed Version' is '2:8723.1-0ubuntu5'.

Both 2 and 3 have '8.723.1' in their versions, but they are different from 1.

My questions is: which one is right? What's the best (official) way to check the version of fglrx?

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, @Uri Herrera. In #1, the version is 8.72.11. In #2, the version is 8.723.1. Which one is the version of FLGRX? I'm still confused.:(

Comment: Dismiss my last comment.. i read it wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you third example,

`ls /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/
8.723.1  kernel-2.6.32-37-generic-x86_64`, that is the FGLRX Driver version.

Here is an image!

[image]

Hope that explains it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use fglrxinfo:

```
user@machine$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose fglrxinfo 2>&1 | grep fglrx
libGL: AtiGetClientDriverName: 8.98.2 fglrx (screen 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the command `env COLUMNS=500 dpkg -l fglrx\*` in a terminal window,  to see the package versions you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

Check "Version Identifier" string inside /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so

Or even simpler check "ReleaseVersion" inside /etc/ati/amdpcsdb